# Will gcc work correctly if "+m" is used as an output constraint?

Tags: c++, gcc, inline-assembly

According to the [gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm) on extended assembler:

*You should only use read-write operands when the constraints for the operand [...] allow a register.*

This seems to be to be pretty unambiguous: You **cannot** use +m for an output.

However, I've seen it being done a number of times.  In fact, Linus Torvalds is [on record](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/gcc_asm.html) as saying

*The gcc docs are secondary. They're not updated, they aren't correct, they don't reflect reality, and they don't matter. The only correct thing to use is "+m" for things like this*

I don't want to use +m if the compiler is going to end up screwing up my code.  And even examining the output asm to see if it is working doesn't mean that tomorrow when I change some seemingly unrelated thing it will still work.  Or that it will still work when I get the next update to gcc.

If the docs are right and I can't depend on this working correctly, I want to know that so I can pursue other options (most of which are unpleasantly painful).  If the docs are wrong, please let me know how to get them corrected.

Comment: This is so specific, it might have been better asked on the gcc mailing list, where maintainers see it...

Comment: Ah the dilemma... On one hand you have the almighty docs one should always refer to, and on the other hand you have a renowned hacker like Linus who says those docs don't matter. I feel your pain. ;) @PlasmaHH is right though, this may well be too specific for SO, better ask the maintainers themselves.

Comment: Ok, but not having used any of these before, which of the gcc lists (http://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html) seems more appropriate?  Is this more of a "general development" question?  Or a bug?

Comment: @PlasmaHH on the flipside, this is essentially a gem of experience, and I love that it is brought to SO. I would have preferred if the "doc ambiguity" was the question, and the "Linus quote" was the (self-)answer, making it less open-ended and more of a service to future SO users looking for prior knowledge in this area. /cc \@David?

Comment: @sehe I personally don't like pure opinions, especially not in this kind of question, as answers on SO. But yeah, it's kind of intresting, otherwise I would have voted to close.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Nonetheless, questions that only a tiny group of individuals that aren't Eric Lippert can actually answer are at least iffy.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd `gcc-help` looks correct. Plain `gcc` seems to be for people working **on** GCC, not **with** it

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm sure it's true that the number of people who can authoritatively **answer** this question is quite limited. However, the number of people who write asm and might need to _know_ this answer is likely to be somewhat larger. And larger still are the number of people who write code and are _impacted_ by asm routines in projects that get this wrong. If an answer can be found here, all 3 groups benefit.  The trick, of course, is can an answer be found.  I'm composing an email for the list now.

Comment: @millimoose Hmm.  It's true, I'm working -with- gcc, so logically that's the right forum.  However, the only people who are going to know the answer for sure are the ones working -on- gcc.  That said, I'm going to take your advice and go for gcc-help.

Comment: @David If that fails (i.e. goes unnoticed by anyone useful) it might still be worth reporting this as a bug in the documentation, referring to the Linus quote. Also, I'd say a reason to not close this is because the question isn't about an arbitrary (-ish) language design decision, as most questions that get closed with "nobody here can really tell you" are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem is the docs (see the [email](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2013-03/msg00276.html)).  In case the link dies:

*That part of the docs has been wrong for a while.  The doc was corrected for 4.8, but it was wrong for earlier versions too.*

Since I am using rubenvb's x64 compiler which reports version 4.7.2, that's the version of the docs I was reading.  However, the actual code checkin was in 2004, so I'm feeling pretty confident that change is included in the code I'm running.

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't cite what Linus had to say on gcc in 2001 (!), when the gcc/egcs rift was just starting to heal (that ended around 2000). Yes, the handling of asm restrictions was a horrendous mess in that timeframe (Alan Cox was sort of head of cleaning the mess up, as the compiler was starting to really heed the restrictions, I added a few patches to that).

The current GCC is a completely different beast, it has undergone extensive reengineering inside.

Believe the documentation, don't write bad constraints. They are *constraints*, if you lie to the compiler, it might by sheer bad luck select arguments that do work most of the time. It *will*  break some day.

*If* you have an example that shows that writing an illegal constraint is accepted (that the compiler can check!), please report it.

*If* you have an example of a constraint that the compiler doesn't consider, please report it.

If you have code that does stuff that might (or not) work depending on options the compiler can legally take according to what ypu told it, and that sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't, OK, chalk it up to your own fault and wise up. **Do not lie to your compiler, it will exact bloody revenge.**

Comment: While I agree in principle, a search of the Linux 3.8.4 kernel source shows 192 instances of the `"+m"` constraint across multiple architectures. This would seem to be a terribly short-sighted error on behalf of the kernel maintainers.

Comment: I wasn't trying to start (or restart) any longstanding arguments.  I only mentioned it as one of the few, credible sources of info I was able to find on the subject.  As it turns out, believing the docs in this case was the wrong answer (see my answer below).  Despite what the docs say, "+m" is indeed a supported constraint.  As for lying to the compiler, it was that very fear that prompted this question.